# How to display the regular price and sale price in single product and loop pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I had this code in function.php of my child theme to display the regular price and sale price and it was working fine in WooCommerce v2.6.14.

But this snippet doesn't work anymore on WooCommerce version 3.2.3.

How can I fix that?

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
$saved = wc_price( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price );
return $price . sprintf( __('<p>Save %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saved );
}
```

Thanks to whoever help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter woocommerce_sale_price_html doesn't exist anymore use `woocommerce_get_price_html` instead.  This will run for everything regardless of of the item being on sale so you'll need to check if the product is on sale in your code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'modify_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );

function modify_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_on_sale() && ! is_admin() )
        return $price . sprintf( __('<p>Save %s</p>', 'woocommerce' ), $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price );
    else
        return $price;
}
```